# Ninject StandardKernel System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1

Tags: xamarin, ninject

I am a learning `Xamarin` and I wanted to use `Ninject` for `IoC` containers and dependency injection. I added `Ninject 3.3.4` using `NuGet` package on `Visual studio 2017` community. I receive error on the following line of code in my App.Xaml.cs:

```
Kernel = new StandardKernel(new TripLogCoreModule(), new TripLogNavModule(mainPage.Navigation));
```

I receive following error:

> Ninject StandardKernel System.ArgumentNullException: value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: path1

I spent about 2 hours on the internet and couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Finally, I found the oversight that I made, so I thought to post this question and answer my own question, in case someone else (newbie like me) make this mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The oversight that I made was that I installed the wrong package. I should have installed `Portable.Ninject`.

In order to fix this, I uninstalled the `Ninject3.3.4` from all my projects and then installed `Portable.Ninject 3.3.1` (latest stable version at the time of writing) via NuGet package.

I hope this helps and saves time for those people who may make similar mistake!

Comment: yes but this is not compatible with .net standard class libraries

Answer (score 8):

Personally, I had the error with both **Ninject** and **Ninject.PCL** packages

Try to build the **StandardKernel** with **NinjectSettings** :

```
var settings = new Ninject.NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false };
Kernel = new StandardKernel(settings, new ViewModelsModule());
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Emmanuel DURIN had the right answer for using Ninject 3.3.4 with Xamarin.Forms .Net Standard.

> var settings = new Ninject.NinjectSettings() { LoadExtensions = false };
>   Kernel = new StandardKernel(settings, new ViewModelsModule());

instead of

> Kernel = new StandardKernel(new ViewModelsModule());